# Non dimmable switch where dimmer switch previously was?

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch, light

I just found that the dimmable switch to my dining room overhead light had stopped working. I currently have 4 dimmable led bulbs in the overhead light. When the light switch (and the overhead light) was working, the LED bulbs created a slight buzz even when the dimmer was up all the way on the switch. I was wondering if I was able to replace the dimmable light switch with a simple on and off switch and if so, would that solve the buzzing problem as well?

Thank you,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

First question would be, are the LED's dimmable? This would be listed on the box it came in. Second question would be, is the dimmer rated for LED's.

Changing the dimmer out for a standard switch would stop the LED's from buzzing if the LED's were not damaged by the dimmer.

Hope this helps

Comment: The LEDs that I am using in the fixture claim that they are dimmable and a switch also says that it is compatible with dimmable LED lights however I still get this light buzzing so I figured I would cut my losses and go back to a simple on and off switch

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes you can change a dimmer to a simple on off switch. The electronics in some dimmers can cause noise if this is the cause the simple on off will eliminate the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Try the bulbs in another, non-dimmed fixture (such as a switched desk lamp). If they don't buzz there, they shouldn't buzz after you change the existing dimmer to a switch.

It's worth testing before installing the new switch because some low-quality LED bulbs buzz all the time. It's also possible these particular bulbs were damaged and will buzz because of that. But buzzing is often louder when a dimmer is in use and converting to a regular switch can help.